# ASP.NET Master Page pageload event

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I've created :
1 - Master Page
2 - Content Pages
3 - Base Page
I'm using page on load event on Master Page to check for logging in state. but apparently after I changed the content pages to :

```
public partial class web-form1 : BasePage
```

the page load event from master page gets executed after the page load of the content page.
how can I force the Master Page load event to come first ?

Comment: Why would you care about the order? Doesn't the login indicator get displayed anyway? What do the event handlers do? In any case, you have *one* page, not multiple. The page that's being loaded is the `Content` page. The master pages is only a template for that content page. I think there's an inheritance relation too, but I haven't used WebForms in more than 10 years.

Comment: `Force Master Page load event first`?. Well, you cannot. It's as simple as that. It will always trigger after the Content Page.

Comment: What is the *real* question? What used to work but doesn't work now? The order of events [is explained in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dct97kc3(v=vs.140)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and can't change. It shouldn't matter either. Are you trying to display different parts to anonymous users? Personalize the page? That's not done by code in a master page Load event

Comment: Thanks for your comments by the way. I just understood the issue. obviously I did too many mistakes into planning. Should have read more about events order. Thank you.